# How can i put it background image on setAttribute method?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a simple program that cuts the circle evenly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGcE2.jpg)

and I want to put it image using 'setAttribute' method.
but, It doesn't work as i thought.

here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="kr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      *{margin:0; padding:0;}
    </style>
  <script>
    function elt(name, attributes){
      var node = document.createElement(name);
      if( attributes ){
        for(var attr in attributes){
          if(attributes.hasOwnProperty(attr)){
            node.setAttribute(attr,attributes[attr]);
          }
        }
      }
      for(var i=2; i<arguments.length; i++){
        var child = arguments[i];
        if( typeof child == "string" ){
          child = document.createTextNode(child);
        }
        node.appendChild(child);
      }
      return node;
    }
    
    window.onload=()=>{
      const IMG_W_COUNT = 50;
      const IMG_H_COUNT = 33;
      const IMG_SUM = 1650;

      for(var i=1,j=0;i<=IMG_SUM;i++,j+=18){
        var ImageSaver = elt("div",{
          class:"menu item"+i,
          width:18+"px",
          height:18+"px",
          background:"url('paint.jpg')",
          backgroundPosition:0+"px"+" "+j+"px"
      });
      document.body.appendChild(ImageSaver);
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The elt function is a function that helps to easily generate an element.
I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background`, `height` and `width` aren't attributes (except on a few elements, and there they are mostly deprecated), nor is `backgroundPosition`.

To set a CSS property value with a function use [`setProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) on a style declaration.

Make sure you use the CSS property name, which is `background-position` not `backgroundPosition`.

```
element.style.setProperty("name", "value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set CSS properties.

```
 element.style.width=18+"px";
 element.style.height=18+"px";
 element.style.background="url('paint.jpg')";
 element.style.backgroundPosition="top right";
```